# Requestmapping para uma URL grande

Tags: java, jdbc, request

Queria saber como eu faço um `@RequestMapping` para uma URL grande. No caso eu queria mapear a palavra autenticar.

```
http://localhost:8080/DataIdea/autenticar?email=0fS3w9wOg6WkJB%2BBdvEmlKxQxYOhF8nqt2lPx801R5M%3D
```

eu estou tentando usar o códgio abaixo, mas não da certo

```
@RequestMapping("autenticar")
public String confirmacao() {
    System.out.println(" autenticado" );
    return "usuarios/confirmacao";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poderia postar o código de sua classe controller?

Supondo que você tenha em seu controller o metadado próximo a sua classe, seu código deveria estar desta maneira:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/DataIdea")
class SuaClasse{

@RequestMapping("/autenticar")
public String confirmacao(@RequestParam("email") String email) {
    System.out.println(" autenticado" );
    return "usuarios/confirmacao";
}

}
```